# Can I manually rerun vim's filetype detection?

Tags: vim

The Kate editor has a nice feature: When you're saving a file, it will rerun its filetype detection. Suppose you want to create a new script in ~/bin, so you say

```
kate ~/bin/myscript
```

Then type e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env perl` and save. In this moment, Kate will recognize that we're talking Perl, and load the syntax highlighting.

In Vim, I thought I could build something similar by means of an autocommand, but I'm stuck with the command that's being executed. I don't see a distinct command for rerunning the filetype detection. It's run by `:edit`, so I could say

```
autocmd BufWritePost * :edit#
```

But that's rude: It esp. loses the undo history, cursor positions, etc. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well there's a command for that:

```
:filetype detect
```

Comment: Thanks! With this pointer, I found `:help filetype-detect` which mentions exactly my use-case.